# Azure KeyVault list pending certificate requests

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

I'm automating certificate request in **Azure Key Vault** and I would like to list all certificate operations (`In progress, Failed or Cancelled`) without knowing the exact certificate name in specific key vault, using powershell so that I can figure out if a new request needs to be created or just wait for approval if there is an existing request. It is only possible  to list completed requests without knowing the certificate name.

The following command will only list completed certificates and I need those in progress, failed or cancelled to be listed.

```
  Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the certificate status one by one through this command:

[**Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.keyvault/get-azurekeyvaultcertificateoperation?view=azurermps-6.1.0)

**update**

---

you can use following scripts to achieve that:

```
$certs = Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName nancykeyvault

foreach ($cert in $certs)
{
  Get-AzureKeyVaultCertificateOperation -VaultName nancykeyvault -Name $cert.Name
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sure, that is possible if you know the name of the certificate and the Name parameter is required. In my case, I don't know the name of the certificate. When I automatically create a cert request the certificate name is derived from DNS names (SAN) and if that specific name is not available the automation will add unique string as suffix to the certificate name. Before it creates new request it must check pending orders.

Comment: Already tested that but it does not list certificates that are in progress, failed or cancelled. Try to set status disabled on one of yours test certs and you will see that those will not be listed using command above or any command.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is not possible to achive using current stable AzureRM.KeyVault module (5.0.0) but there is a preview version 5.1.0 that supports listing certificates in a pending state. Just tested that version and yes it does what I want but must wait until it hits stable version.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM.KeyVault/5.1.0-preview

Anybody have a workaround until key vault module is stable?